# loading disk image into NSImage

Tags: swift, appkit

I am trying to create a CALayer to apply to my view.  But, before I even get to that I cannot get an image to load from disk.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: "/Users/Shared/background.png")!
        let imageView = NSImageView(image: image)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

I have used contentsOfFile as well as byReferencingFile and it doesn't change the behavior.  The file exists at that path.

**UPDATE:** This doesn't work either.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/carroll/Desktop/background.jpg")
        let image = NSImage(contentsOf: fileURL)
        print(image)
        let imageView = NSImageView(image: image)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

So this is what is printing to the console:

> Optional(<NSImage 0x600003310aa0 Size={576, 828} Reps=(
> "NSBitmapImageRep 0x60000260e4c0 Size={576, 828} ColorSpace=(not yet > loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=2400x3450 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600000246a60"
> )>)
>
> 2020-08-10 11:46:57.767358-0500 My App[83208:8822749] Metal API Validation Enabled
> 2020-08-10 11:46:57.832881-0500 My App[83208:8822749] VPA info: plugin is INTEL, AVD_id = 1080010, AVD_api.Create:0x131373c15

From what I see above from the print statement it looks like it is getting the image, but it shows not loaded yet and then for the CurrentBacking it shows nil (faulting).

**UPDATE 2** I was able to get the background to display, but I do not understand why this works and why I have to have set `self.view.wantsLayer = true` when the Apple Documentation says this property is already set to true as default.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        let image = NSImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Shared/background.jpg"))
        self.view.layer?.contents = image
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure your app sandbox is turned off

Comment: It is turned off (deleted).  Still no-go.

Comment: Try creating the fileURL and load the Data and check the error.

Comment: I tried that and I added an update to my question above.  I also moved the background file to my Desktop because everything was nil when it was in /Users/Shared, even though I have sandboxing turned off (deleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be mixing up with the iOS behaviour.

iOS `UIView` has `wantsLayer` **`true`** by default, whereas macOS `NSView` has `wantsLayer` **`false`** by default (for backwards compatibility with older apps I suspect?).

For macOS you will need to manually set `wantsLayer` on the view to **`true`** to be able to use layers in your view.

(I know this is an older question but still begs an answer)